# Jquery - Designing a report builder web tool

Tags: jquery

I am looking to develop a report builder tool and thought if I could use JQuery for this.
Basically, what I am looking for is to have a screen that shows a list of field in the left hand side (something like a tree view). I can select a field and then drag it to a panel in the right hand side and drop it there. As I add more fields, the fields are all lines up side by side to each other. This is the basic starting point I am looking for and will build further features on this.
Any suggestion on how to do this using jquery. Can anyone point of to any available resource that I could use or refer to?

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
A.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you could provide some images or sth more material to help you.

I would say that more or less you will find sth to work with Jquery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement